# React - Router inside a element using class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do i render a react component using class?

I have the following code:

```
class PageLogin extends React.Component {

    render() { 
       return (<p>hello</p>)
    }
}
export default PageLogin
```

When i import it, it render the component entirely, updating the page, so how do i inject it into a div in the component that is rendered?

Comment: can u setup a demo, that would help us to debug

Comment: I can, but not now(serious problems here). But we have the method ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('id')) where i can specify where do i want it to render, how to do this with class? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use document.getElementsByClassName or document.querySelector methods

Comment: I mean javascript class component extendes React.component, not css classes

Comment: @ThiagoSouza `ReactDOM.render(<PageLogin />, document.getElementById('id'))` will render the `PageLogin` component.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Thank for the answer. I know that, but if i'm using a class like i've show above? how to tell to the render method of the class to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah okay, I think I see what you mean. By default, you can't specify where an individual component is rendered. You tell your main component to render in `<div id="id"></div>`, so that means EVERY component will use that div as the render root.

However, as of React v16 you can use [ReactDOM.createPortal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) to render a component in any element.

```
class PageLogin extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {ReactDOM.createPortal(<p>hello</p>, document.getElementById('anotherRoot'))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default PageLogin
```

Ideally though, you'd want to move that code to wherever you are rendering `PageLogin`:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {ReactDOM.createPortal(<PageLogin />, document.getElementById('anotherRoot'))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what i was searching for